# Check existence of point on leaflet route

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet

Is there are a method on leaflet routing machine that checks if a specific point, e.g (lat,lng), is inside the routing polyline ?

Answer (score 2):

There is not, but it's still doable using [Leaflet.GeometryUtil](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.GeometryUtil)

Take a look at the [belongsSegment](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#belongsSegment) function:

```
belongsSegment(latlng, latlngA, latlngB, toleranceopt, nullable) → {boolean}

Returns true if the latlng belongs to segment A-B
```

So when a route is selected in Routing Machine, you are checking for every segment of a polyline if the point belongs to it with a given tolerance:

```
var point = {your specific point};
...
map.on('routeselected', function(e) {
    var route = e.route;
    isPointOnLine(point, route.coordinates));
})
```

where isPointOnLine is

```
function isPointOnLine(point, path) {
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
        if (L.GeometryUtil.belongsSegment(point, path[i], path[i + 1])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```